# Dapper.Net SQL bulk insert decimal precision

Tags: dapper, sqlbulkcopy

I am getting an exception from `Dapper Bulk Copy`
Looks like the underlying bulk copy operation is failing. I dumped the data in json and found the value creating problem is `259815703.3430760631`

```
StackTrace:
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.ConvertValue(Object value, _SqlMetaData metadata, Boolean isNull, Boolean& isSqlType, Boolean& coercedToDataFeed)
.....
Inner Exception 1:
InvalidOperationException: The given value of type Decimal from the data source 
cannot be converted to type decimal of the specified target column.

 Inner Exception 2:
 ArgumentException: Parameter value '259815703.34307606' is out of range
```

The table has `decimal(18,6)` and instead of storing with lower precision the API is throwing.

I tried the following and it works, the value that is stored is 6 decimal instead of 10 as expected

```
CREATE TABLE #t1(c1 DECIMAL(18,6))
INSERT INTO #t1(c1) values(259815703.3430760631)
```

Comment: Are ANSI_WARNINGS on or off in your session?

Comment: Hi Alex, Thanks for looking into my question ANSI_WARNINGS is ON for the DB. I solved the issue with decimal.Round to 6 places of decimal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue with decimal.Round to 6 places of decimal